# error with my query trying to add Total if IS NULL on using WITH ROLLUP

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to remove unnecessary values being fetched when exporting data into csv using clause with rollup but somehow its throwing up error and i am not getting any results.

could someone see what am i doing wrong?

my actual query which works but in the results of total some unnecessary values also gets printed

```
SELECT sale_id, reference, pname AS product, price, 
sold_to, SUM(pquantity) AS quantity, 
SUM(pamount) AS amount, 
date FROM sales WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' 
GROUP BY sale_id WITH ROLLUP");
```

and what i tried to remove those and insteat write TOTAL then the actual count

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT sale_id, 
       CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN pname AS product END pname AS product, 
       CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN price END price, 
       CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN sold_to END sold_to, 
       CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(pquantity) AS quantity END SUM(pquantity) AS quantity, 
       CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(pamount) AS amount ELSE 'TOTAL' END SUM(pamount) AS amount, 
       CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN date END date
FROM sales WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' GROUP BY sale_id WITH ROLLUP");
```

please help me experts.

Thanks

Comment: *CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(pquantity) **AS quantity** END **SUM(pquantity)** AS quantity* - ??? what's this?

Comment: I am lost on what result set you want.  One produces many rows, the other many columns.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff basically the first query on the question above does display desired data on csv file but where the total amount shows those lines are with with some values i have no idea from where its getting fetched so i am trying to get rid of those and add TOTAL instead

Comment: Your chain of questions is called stack overflow-driven development and generally frowned upon. You should invest some effort on your part, other than just accepting one answer and then re-asking the question again, just copy-pasting the recent answer to the new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have improper AS and sum() mixed  with case

remove the improper AS alias and use sum ouside the case

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT sale_id, 
             CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN pname END product
           , CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN price END price
           , CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN sold_to END sold_to
           , SUM( CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN pquantity  ELSE 0 END )  quantity
           , SUM( CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN pamount ELSE 0  END )  amount
           , CASE WHEN sale_id IS NOT NULL THEN date END date
    FROM sales WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' 
    GROUP BY sale_id WITH ROLLUP");
```

Comment: still getting error. htmls codes in csv file

Comment: naswer updated ..

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS product

Comment: still htmnl codes outputting in the csv file

Comment: wrong AS producet removed

Comment: mate but i need to change the name from pname to product in output csv file?

Comment: answer updated ..

Comment: Thanks aton you saved me :)